# Minor trouble with SED and variables

Tags: regex, linux, bash, unix, sed

**Hey guys and girls.**

I'm new here, please be kind :). Yeah, i got some problem...
I was writing some script and always used the absolute path to my document folder. Some stuff like this:

```
cd /home/myname/documents/blabla/
```

More-or-les finished, i wanted to clear up the code, make it available for others and change it to something like this:

```
VARIABLE="/home/myname/documents"
cd $VARIABLE/blabla
```

And because there are over 9000 absolute paths in the script, i naturally thought about using SED to "clean up" my script. And here comes the problem:

```
sed -ie "s|home/myname/documents|$VARIABLE|g" script1
```

This gives me of course empty spaces. I want to exchange the path with the string "$VARIABLE" and not with the Variable itself. Tried out some stuff like quotation marks, some brackets but couldn't figure out how it could work.

So i apply to you. Could you help me?
I could really take some sleep...^^

Thanks alot and sorry for my english. A n00bie.

Comment: Are you sure you are using double quotes? If so, there shouldn't be a problem. The literal `$VARIABLE` will only appear if you use single quotes. Also, it is a good practice to backup the file, just in case: `sed -i.bak ...`

Comment: @fedorqui I think you got what he wants backwards, he actually wants `$VARIABLE` literally and needs single quotes :)

Comment: Oooops true :) +1 for you for reading properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just change `"` to `'` to not expand variable but treat the text literally:

```
sed -ie 's|home/myname/documents|$VARIABLE|g' script1
```

EDIT: Be careful about the initial `/` too, just so you don't miss that your regexp doesn't remove that.

Comment: That was it! Thanks a lot for the speedy answer ^^

Comment: use `#` (or another non "Regex" char) instead of `|` on GNU sed, yoiu could easily make an error if passing in extended regex creating a OR in place of a separator (with a failing sed instruction also)

Comment: @TimonTigerli Glad to help, don't forget to mark answer as correct if it fulfills your requirement and answers the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -ie "s#home/myname/documents#\$VARIABLE#g" script1
```

alternative, escape the `$`

Comment: One should always use single quotes for regexp (and other stuff) when used in a shell to prevent shell expansion where it's not wanted.

Comment: "always" is a bit excessif but agree on the principe to avoid double quoute if possible

Comment: It's hard on a place like this to say "almost always" or equivalent because then people start wonder about when it's ok to not do it. So basically: Always do it and when you don't need to do it you know why and don't need to ask :)